# Error when running on python idle

Tags: python

Update: I deleted the .dat file where everything is saved and now it works again. I would like some input on what might have caused it anything will help. I just want to know how to prevent it in the future.

---

Everything work perfectly yesterday using python idle.
Today I edited my program in pycharm to add a delete account feature. Everything runs on pycharm I can receive accounts, delete accounts, and create them. I decided to test it on idle because most computers I work on I can't download pycharm and I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Passwords\password.py", line 140, in ?
    program_start()
  File "E:\Passwords\password.py", line 137, in program_start
    all_accounts()
  File "E:\Passwords\password.py", line 93, in all_accounts
    klist = f.keys()
  File "C:\Python24\lib\shelve.py", line 98, in keys
    return self.dict.keys()
  File "C:\Python24\lib\bsddb\__init__.py", line 244, in keys
    return self.db.keys()
DBRunRecoveryError: (-30978, 'DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery -- accounts.dat: pgin failed for page 1')
```

I decided to run on pycharm again and against all odds it still ran perfectly no errors. What does this error mean? How can I fix it? And what causes it? 
Also I have tried to run it on multiple computers to see if python idle would run it and none of them would. 
Did the delete function ruin it?

```
def delete_account():
    """Deletes an account"""
    print'\n'
    account = raw_input("What account do you want to delete?: ")
    f = shelve.open("accounts.dat")
    if account in f:
        confirm_deletion = raw_input("Are you sure you want to delete " + account + "?: ")
        if confirm_deletion.lower() in ('yes', 'y'):
            del f[account]
            print "This account has been deleted."
        else:
            print "Canceled... "
    else:
        print "I'm sorry we could not find any account related to " + account
    print '\n'
    f.close
```

Or did pycharm cause this error?

Comment: Check what version of python pycharm use. It could be pycharm is using a different version than idle-python (just a guess)

Comment: @Xorg Thanks for the feedback I'm honestly looking for anything that could be it. I'm using the latest pycharm and using python 2.4.4 which is pretty old for this specific program

Comment: try this link..https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2bvyz1/gui_code_runs_fine_in_idle_but_not_pycharm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check your python version**

It could be pycharm is using a different version of python as compared to the idle you have installed.